# Error while using VWRITE command in ANSYS APDL

Tags: structural-engineering, solid-mechanics, ansys-apdl

I am writing code in APDL for a nonlinear structural analysis of a plate.
Following is the Post processing part which returns a formatting error. Help will be appreciated in identifying the problem and solution.

```
'''/POST1
NSEL,S,LOC,X,40
NSEL,R,LOC,Y,0
*GET,NA,NODE,0,NUM,MIN
NSEL,S,LOC,X,40
NSEL,R,LOC,Y,30
*GET,NB,NODE,0,NUM,MIN
ALLSEL
*DO,I,1,5
SET,I
/OUTPUT,ADISP,OUT,,APPEND
*VWRITE,UX(NA),UY(NA),UZ(NA)
(E16.8,5X, E16.8,5X, E16.8,5X)
/OUTPUT
/OUTPUT,BDISP,OUT,,APPEND
*VWRITE,UX(NB),UY(NB),UZ(NB)
(E16.8,5X, E16.8,5X, E16.8,5X)
/OUTPUT
*ENDDO
*END'''
```

Comment: In the graphical user interface, the *VWRITE command can only be executed from an external file such as /INPUT or *USE. The command is ignored.

*** WARNING *** CP = Error in format, not enough data format specifiers 3.250

*** WARNING ***

(E16.8,5 is not a recognized BEGIN command, abbreviation, or macro. This command will be ignored.

Comment: Seems like you just paste the code into the MAPDL directly. VWRITE has to be part of macro file (located in the job folder), which you can run by typing its name into MAPDL.

Comment: Or, write the bit of code you are interested in in a `.txt` file and from the menu click on "File/Read Input from", then select the file you created in any folder you want (that's equivalent to the `/input`, defined in the help as `/INPUT, F(ile)name, Ext(ension), Dir(ectory), LINE, LOG`.